# Ratio<,> is constant, but what if I want to accept different ratios as an argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, std, rational-numbers

Perhaps an oxymoronic question: [ratio<,>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio) is, by definition, a compile-time constant.

However, I would like to construct durations with different ratios that can be specified by the caller of my method. I'm guessing I should be using something other than ratio and/or duration, then, but what?

I want to have, say, a class member that can be set at runtime, and I would like it to be of type ratio<,>. At some point in the code, where this member gets set/assigned, it would be assigned a constant ratio, but in my class, I don't want to specify what that ratio should be.

Comment: Can you include some code? I feel like I understand the gist of your question but it's quite unclear

Comment: I assume by "can be specified by the caller" you mean that the ratio is specified during runtime? That would make a huge difference - otherwise construction the ratio is rather trivial (just set the template parameters accordingly).

Comment: Why not just have the ratio as arguments? Or keep a struct around with the ratio defined?

Comment: @Clearer, when you say "ratio as arguments", do you mean, not using `ratio<,>` at all? I couldn't do that because the code that uses it requires a ratio (e.g., `duration<,,>`, etc. - see the example in https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/chrono/duration#Example). Not sure about keeping the struct around. The whole point, it seems, is that the ratio must be constant, but that means durations must be constant, etc., etc. Not very flexible.

Comment: Yes, I meant not using `ratio<,>`. Durations do not have to be constant, just because their types are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, you need a `std::ratio` which *"can be specified by the caller"*. There are three different options:

- The caller wants to set `std::ratio` template parameters during **compile time**. This is trivial, simply set the parameters, e.g. `using quarter = std::ratio<1, 4>`.
- The caller wants to set `std::ratio` template parameters during **runtime**. This is not possible by definition, `std::ratio` is a *compile-time constant*. You will have to implement your own class for computing ratios during runtime or use some kind of library (I don't know of any, suggestions welcome!).
- The caller merely wants to scale a `std::duration` (which is what you seem to use your `std::ratio` for). Then just [multiply it with a number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4).

Comment: I want something in-between: I want to have, say, a class member that can be set at runtime, and I would like it to be of type ratio<,>. At some point in the code, where this member gets set/assigned, it would be assigned a constant ratio, but in my class, I don't want to specify what that ratio should be.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't make a difference to the second option, if I understood you correctly. It doesn't matter whether your ratio is constant or not throughout runtime, it won't be a compile-time constant if you can set it/assign to it _after_ compilation (of course :-)).

Comment: As I said, I would go with some kind of ratio class that you can populate at runtime. That's the only option you have. Unfortunately I don't know of any library providing such a class and googling for "C++ ratio" isn't really helpful, as you can image...

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to think of some other way to solve my problem, then. Thanks!

Comment: @TatianaRacheva, I updated my answer. It just crossed my mind after your update that you might simply want to scale your time duration?

Comment: Ah, that might actually be what I need! I don't think I really need an arbitrary ratio/duration. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The answer illustrates a common approach with C++ templates:

```
template<typename ratio_type>
returnvalue function_name(ratio_type const& r, other parameter...)
{ ... }
```

The point is, that the very type of the ratio contains information. Since types (often, but not always) are the parameters passed to templates, you forward those parameters via templates, too. Of course, this only shifts the problem to a different place, so at some point you will take the numerator and denominator from the ratio and use it as values.

BTW: Consider `std::div` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div) as alternative.

Comment: This is pretty helpful, too.